# Graphing and limits?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

So the question here is 
"Consider the following graph of $f(x)= -(x-4)^2 + 4 $, making minor changes to the graph, draw the situation below:

$\large\lim f(x)_{ x\to 4^+}$  does not exist

$\large\lim f(x)_{ x\to 4^-}$  does not exist

So basically i'm trying to figure out what the graph would look like if those limits were true

Comment: do you mean minor changes to the equation?

Comment: The question says the graph (there's a picture of the original graph and it wants us to show what it would look like after the limits were put in place), but yes I'm assuming the equation would be changed

Comment: $\frac{-1}{(x-4)^2}+4$ tends to $-\infty$ as $x\to 4-$ and $x \to 4+$

Answer (score 0):

The limit doesn't exist means that either the limit is not unique or the limit is not finite.

First of all check the graph of $f$.

In the case were it's not unique take for example the following piece-wise defined function g: 
if $x>4$ then g is f
if $x \le 4$ then $g(x)$ is $f(x)+1$
Thus the limit for 4+ is 4 and the limit at 4- is 5
5 is not equal to 4 thus the limit is not unique and thus doesn't exist at 4. Check the graph here https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kqvxyxcqne

However for the other case you can't have minor changes to f since you need the limit to be infinite. One way for doing that is to have something in the dominator that's close to 0 when x is close to 4 so for example check the function $h(x)=f(x)/(x-4)$. Check its graph here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1i0p5skiqu